# CsvHelper Map constructor parameters don't change

Tags: c#, asp.net, csv, mapping, csvhelper

Appears I have a problem:

```csharp
private static class Maps
{
    public sealed class LineMap : ClassMap<EdiLine>
    {
        public LineMap(DBProduct products, EdiDocument? document = null)
        {
            Map().Ignore().Index(0);                                                                                                        // A - NISACI
            Map().Ignore().Index(1);                                                                                                        // B - Line Type (H,D,S,T)
            Map().Ignore().Index(2);                                                                                                        // C - Document Type
            Map().Ignore().Index(3);                                                                                                        // D - Account Number
            Map().Ignore().Index(4);                                                                                                        // E - Invoice Number
            Map().Ignore().Index(5);                                                                                                        // F - Invoice Date
            Map().Ignore().Index(6);                                                                                                        // G - Unused (-1)

            Map(p => p.File_SupplierCode).Index(7);                                                                                         // H - Supplier Product Code
            Map(p => p.Product).Convert(p =>
                products.GetBySupplierProductCodeAsync(document?.SupplierID!, p.Row.GetField(7)).Result).Index(7);                          // H - Supplier Product Code
                // document.SupplierID is always the same value, the one passed for the first LineMap

            Map(p => p.File_Description).Index(8);                                                                                          // I - Supplier Product Description
            Map(p => p.Quantity).Index(9);                                                                                                  // J - Quantity
            Map(p => p.File_CaseNetCost).Index(10);                                                                                         // K - Case Cost
            Map(p => p.File_VatRate).Convert(p => decimal.Parse(p.Row.GetField(11)) / 100).Index(11);                                       // L - Vat Rate x100
            Map(p => p.File_LineNetCost).Index(12);                                                                                         // M - Line Net Cost
            Map(p => p.File_LineVatCost).Index(13);                                                                                         // N - Line VAT Amount
            Map(p => p.File_LineGrossCost).Index(14);                                                                                       // O - Line Gross Cost
            Map().Ignore().Index(15);                                                                                                       // P - NISA Supplier ID
            Map().Ignore().Index(16);                                                                                                       // Q - NISA Supplier Description
        }
    }
}
```

(I've shortened the next method or it'd be ridiculous)

```csharp
protected override async Task<List<EdiDocument>?> ParseLinesAsync(CsvReader reader)
{
    var Reader = reader;
    EdiDocument? Document;
    while (await Reader.ReadAsync())
    {
        switch (Reader.GetField(1))
        {
            case "H":
                {
                    Document = Reader.GetRecord<EdiDocument>();
                    break;
                }
            case "D":
                {
                    Reader.Context.RegisterClassMap(new Maps.LineMap(Products, Document));
                    Document?.Lines.Add(Reader.GetRecord<EdiLine>());
                    Reader.Context.UnregisterClassMap<Maps.LineMap>();
                    break;
                }
            case "XYZ":
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

The Csv that is being read is attached here (couldn't fit it in the post, sorry):
https://pastebin.com/fMspShA1

The first record, csv lines 1-12 is mapped to an EdiDocument object completely as expected.

When the value of column P changes from 11155A to 15990A on csv line 13, this is correctly mapped to Document.SupplierID after GetRecord in the "H" case.

When the LineMap class is registered again as a class map in the "D" case, the new EdiDocument is passed to the constructor parameter 'document', however, when mapping, it references the original value of the 'document' parameter where the SupplierID is 11155A not 15990A.

Not sure if some sort of caching is occurring or how CsvHelper manages this but I'd figure re-registering the class for each line would pass the most up-to-date document to the constructor for the Map() methods to reference.

Please help, cheers!

Ryan

Comment: I have found that once you start reading, you can't unregister a `ClassMap`.  It gets cached and you can't update or change it.

Comment: Possibly relevant: the doc page [Reading Multiple Data Sets](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/examples/reading/reading-multiple-data-sets/).

Comment: Is there any chance you could [edit] your post to share a [mcve]?  See: [ask].

Comment: I'll setup an example soon as I get 5, seems so far @DavidSpecht is correct. For now I created a static dictionary where I'm storing the SupplierID indexed by an identifier for the file it's processing.